# Accessing an object returns undefined while it's not

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript but I'm a long time programmer and I just can't understand what's happening.

I have this:

```
var MainTable = {
    "k1": 0,
    "k2": 9,
    "k3": 20
};
```

And when I want to access a specific element:

```
var index = "k1";
var value = MainTable[index];
```

And now, for a reason that totally eludes me, it returns undefined instead of 0 each and every time. I've been at it for about 2 hours now and I just don't get it.

Thanks !

EDIT with full code:

```
// These shouldn't be modified
var maxEPoints = 29;
var maxGold = 50;
var hudBarWidth_HR = 650; // 650 is for hr (px)
var hudBarWidth_LR = 350;

var IN_COMBAT = false;
var IN_COMBAT_WAITING = false;

var WolfDamageTable = 
{
    "m11_1": 99,
    "m11_2": 99,
    "m11_3": 8,
    "m11_4": 8,
    "m11_5": 7,
    "m11_6": 6,
    "m11_7": 5,
    "m11_8": 4,
    "m11_9": 3,
    "m11_10": 0,
};

var EnemyDamageTable =
{
    "m11_1": 0,
    "m11_2": 0,
    "m11_3": 0,
    "m11_4": 0,
    "m11_5": 1,
    "m11_6": 2,
    "m11_7": 3,
    "m11_8": 4,
    "m11_9": 5,
    "m11_10": 6,
};


function ComputeCombatDamage( aPoints, ePoints, skill, endurance )
{
    var ratio = ( aPoints - parseInt( skill ) ).toString();
    var absRatio = ( aPoints - parseInt( skill ) );
    var randVal = GIMME_A_RANDOM().toString();

    $( "td#tableWolfSkill" ).html( aPoints.toString() );
    $( "td#tableWolfEndurance" ).html( ePoints.toString() );
    $( "td#ratio" ).html( ratio.toString() + " / " + randVal.toString() );

    // ... code where I process the string index

    var eDamage = EnemyDamageTable[eIndex]; // -> problem
    var wDamage = WolfDamageTable[wIndex];

    var wolfEndurance = ePoints - wDamage;
    var enemyEndurance = endurance - eDamage; 

    var barWidth = ( wolfEndurance / maxEPoints ) * hudBarWidth_HR;


    IN_COMBAT = wolfEndurance > 0 && enemyEndurance > 0;

    return IN_COMBAT;
}

/*********************************************************************
 * custom function to initiate the battle sequence
 *********************************************************************/
function LoadBattle()
{
    IN_COMBAT = true;

    var aPoints = 0;
    var ePoints = 0;
    var gold = 0;

    var name = $( "span#enemyName" ).html();
    var skill = $( "span#enemySkill" ).html();
    var endurance = $( "span#enemyEndurance" ).html();

    if( skill.length == 0 ||
        endurance.length == 0 )
    {
        alert( "Content is not properly formated for combat!" );
        return;
    }

    window.location = "#fight_start";
    // Set up the table before showing it
    $( "td#tableEnemyName" ).html( name );
    $( "td#tableEnemySkill" ).html( skill );
    $( "td#tableEnemyEndurance" ).html( endurance );

    var keepGoing = true;

    while( IN_COMBAT )
    {
        if( typeof( Storage ) !== "undefined" )
        {
            aPoints = localStorage.aPoints;
            ePoints = localStorage.ePoints;
        }
        keepGoing = ComputeCombatDamage( aPoints, ePoints, skill, endurance );
        //endurance = $( "td#enemyResultEndurance" ).html();
        if( keepGoing == false )
        {
            break;
        }
        //WaitCombat();
    }
}
```

To me the error seems to come from

```
var eDamage = EnemyDamageTable[eIndex];
var wDamage = WolfDamageTable[wIndex];
```

In `function ComputeCombatDamage`

I've minimized it as much as possible now.

Comment: *"And now, for a reason that totally eludes me, it returns undefined instead of 0"* Not with the code above, it doesn't. You'll need to show more of your code, as you've omitted the bit actually causing that problem.

Comment: I think your `MainTable` is overwritten somewhere else in between.

Comment: Separately: That's not an array, that's an object.

Comment: Your code works fine. Did you check what happens with some developer tools?

Comment: Okay, so now you've gone too far the other way. What you need to do is create a [**minimal**, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) replicating the problem.

Comment: You don't say what your target environment is, but in the most common environments (a browser or NodeJS), your `WaitInCombat` function will never return and will (on a browser) cause an error from the browser. JavaScript on browsers (and in NodeJS, at the moment) is **single-threaded**. If your have code doing a busy-wait loop, like your `WaitInCombat`, **that's all that will happen**. No other code will run. I can't think of an environment where a busy-wait loop is a good idea (it just burns CPU), but it's a particularly bad idea in single-threaded environments.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line where you're getting an unexpected result and look at `eIndex`, you **will** find that it is not one of the keys you've used in the object. Just use the debugger built into your browser (if your target environment is a browser).

Answer (score 1):

`wIndex` and `eIndex` are not defined. I could elaborate more, but that should say it all.